# Regex: Finding pairs not inside certain tags

Tags: regex

I'm working on a minimal mark up language and I'm trying to allow users to italic text with /slashes/.  I can't seem to get a regex that works correctly, however.

A RegexPal link is [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%5C%2F%5B%5E%28%5C%2F%7C%5C%3C%7C%5C%3E%29%5D%2a%5B%5E%5C%2F%5D%2a%5C%2F&input=I%20am%20attempting%20to%20replace%20values%20in%20%2Fslashes%2F%20with%20italic%20tags.%20%20The%20challenge%3A%20the%20mark%20up%20allows%20URLs%20to%20be%20placed%20into%20%5Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fs%5D%20square%20bracket%20tags%2C%20messing%20things%20up%20further.%20%20Now%20the%20tags%20are%20off%20balanced.%20%20What%20%2Fdo%2F%20I%20do%3F%20%20I%27d%20ideally%20like%20to%20have%20it%20skip%20searching%20%5B%5D%20tags%3F).

Here is what I have so far and doesn't quite work:

```
\/[^(\/|\<|\>)]*[^\/]*\/
```

The value I'm testing against:

```
I am attempting to replace values in /slashes/ with italic tags.  The challenge: the mark up allows URLs to be placed into [http://www.google.com/s] square bracket tags, messing things up further.  Now the tags are off balanced.  What /do/ I do?  I'd ideally like to have it skip searching [] tags?
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want reconciled to life, chose a different character that is not always in html tags.

Comment: problem [solved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: You're probably right.  But I do have the same issue with other markup tags like * and _.  I'd like to try and solve this, even if I change the character later.

Comment: basically if any nesting can occur you **CANNOT** use a regex

Comment: You need a parser that uses regex, not just regex. Then you can use shorter regex and leave the conditional parts up to the parser.

Comment: @aaronman Thanks - I think I get the idea.  :)  The approach would be unstable at best.  I'll un-ask the question.

Comment: No reason to delete it, it is good for people to see since the question is asked so many times

Comment: Actually, the problem may not be as bad as I present it.  The end-user uses pure plain text/markup.  It is just my back-end that converts it to HTML.  I can probably fix that.  So let me adjust my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, the idea is to match html tags or content inside brackets before and replace them by themselves.

```
var str = "I am attempting to replace values in /slashes/ with italic tags.  One problem is HTML: If I do <b>html</b> <b>tags</b> tags, it picks up the closures.  Also, the mark up allows URLs to be placed into [http://www.google.com/s] square bracket tags, messing things up further.  Now the tags are off balanced.  What /do/ I do?  I'd ideally like to have it skip searching [] and inside <> tags.  Doing <b>/italic/</b> should be legal, however.";

str = str.replace(/<[^>]+>|\[[^\]]+\]|\/([^\/]*)\//g, function (m, p1) { 
    return (p1) ? '<i>' + p1 + '</i>' : m; });

console.log(str);
```

Comment: This still grabs a slash within the [ ] brackets, but I think your approach is correct.  I should first use a regex to filter out what should be off-limits.  Then I can do a search against just that more limited text.  Once I find the matches, I can replace it against the original string.

Comment: @Anthony: for the brackets you must do the same, see my edit.

Comment: This is very good and solves the question I posted, though I still have to do it a different way, as it breaks nested tags like */Bold and Italic/*.  I'll probably have to use much more logic.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Description

I think the way I'd approach this is to match everything bad along with everything good. Then in the expression only put your regular expression. Later in the programming logic I'd test each match to see if capture group 1 was populated, if so then the match.index will show where in the string that match occurred.

This regex will:

- match plain text urls, thereby preventing them from being captured in group 1
- match the contents of all html tags,  thereby preventing them from being captured in group 1
- will match the desired `/` bracketed text like `/match me/` into capture group 1

`https?:\/\/[^\s]*|<\/?\w+\b(?=\s|>)(?:='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*|[^>])*>|(\/[^(\/|\<|\>)]*[^\/]*\/)`

[image]

## Example

**Sample Text**

```
I am attempting to replace values in /slashes/ with italic tags.  One problem is HTML: If I do <b>html</b> <b>tags</b> tags, it picks up the closures.  Also, the mark up allows URLs to be placed into [http://www.google.com/s] square bracket tags, messing things up further.  Now the tags are off balanced.  What /do/ I do?  I'd ideally like to have it skip searching [] and inside <> tags.  Doing <b>/italic/</b> should be legal, however.
```

**Matches**

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => /slashes/
        [1] => <b>
        [2] => </b>
        [3] => <b>
        [4] => </b>
        [5] => http://www.google.com/s]
        [6] => /do/
        [7] => <b>
        [8] => /italic/
        [9] => </b>
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => /slashes/
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
        [6] => /do/
        [7] => 
        [8] => /italic/
        [9] => 
    )
```

Comment: That makes sense too - use logic to test for false positives.  Sounds like a decent way to do it!